# Quote comments with replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to transform this:

```
[quote=mvneobux]My first comment[/quote]
I liked your comment.
```

In that:

```
<div class="quote">
    <div class="author">mvneobux:</div>
    My first comment.
</div>
I liked your comment.
```

My solution:

```
comment.replace('#\[quote=(.+?)\](.+?)\[/quote\]#', '<div class="quote"><div class="author"> $1 </div> $2 </div></blockquote> texto: $2'),
```

But it just doesn't work. Can you help me ?

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what? Can you give some sample output?

Comment: Tip: You may want `([^\[]*)` as your interior match, not `(.+?)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex has a problem.

```
#\[quote=(.+?)\](.+?)\[/quote\]#
```

- `#`: matches the character # literally. **But**, your string has not the character. You have to delete the character.
- `/`: **pattern error** in Javascript. You have to add backslash to escape the character.

**So**, your regex should be following syntax.

```
\[quote=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/quote\]
```

```js
var string = `[quote=mvneobux]My first comment[/quote]
I liked your comment.`;
var result = string.replace(/\[quote=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/quote\]/, '<div class="quote"><div class="author"> $1 </div> $2 </div></blockquote> texto: $2');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: but in the following scenario the result is broken:

``[quote=username2][quote=mvneobux]interessante e bom continue[/quote][/username2]``
How can I solve? remembering that there may be several quotes within each other. How could I take each one separately?

Comment: @1001SongsClips In case of many quotes, could you please give output expected?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /^\[quote=(.*)\](.*)\[\/quote\]\n(.*)/;
const string = `[quote=mvneobux]My first comment[/quote]
I liked your comment.`;
const replacement = `<div class="quote">
    <div class="author">$1:</div>
    $2
</div>
$3`;
const result = string.replace(regex, replacement);
console.log(result);
```

You can also see it here: https://regex101.com/r/3CRrP8/1

Answer (score 0):

One alternative:

```js
let str = `[quote=mvneobux]My first comment[/quote]
I liked your comment.`

let result = str.replace(/(?:\[quote=)(.*?)(?:\])(.*?)\[\/quote\]/, '<div class="quote"><div class="author">$1:</div>$2</div>')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let reg = /\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/g;

let str = '[quote=mvneobux]My first comment[/quote]';

let result = str.replace(reg, '<div class="quote"><div class="author"> $1 </div> $2 </div>');

console.log(result) // "<div class="quote"><div class="author"> mvneobux </div> My first comment </div>"
```